# Would a siding contractor be likely to pull this sort of fast one?

Tags: siding

Some contractors are quoting me one amount at a certain number of squares.

Others are quoting almost double, at almost double the amount of squares.

I'm wondering if I'm being paranoid when I fear that the lower quotes will end up saying mid job that they need more squares and I end up paying more anyway.

Is that a thing that happens? Or am I being paranoid?

All contractors in question appear to be reputable.

Comment: A square will cover so many sq ft., height by length on a house.  You measure the four(or more) sides and get square footage.  Take off the sq ft of windows/doors and add the sections that cover the attic sides.  Add a square or two for wastage and you know who is right.  Must compare squares that cover the same.

Comment: As @crip659states, you can get a pretty good idea of how much square footage your siding is. I'll add that in my experience, wildly varying estimates are usually due to one of your contractors being inexperienced. There are some shady characters out there so someone may be trying to take advantage but I usually try to give someone the benefit of the doubt until evidence suggests otherwise. Measure your house and question the estimates.

Comment: You should be asking these questions to the contractors you're dealing with, not us.

Comment: Make sure you are comparing apples to apples.  Are all the quotes for the same siding or different types?

Comment: It should be trivial for you to measure the siding needed for your house and subtract the windows. Get a laser measuring tape for $40. Maybe the quote with double is that guy's "I'd rather not do this" price.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The question would be how much for (1000) squares, not how many squares do I have

Comment: what is the square footage of your home ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get quotes for the job.  You then pick a quote and have a contract written up for the price of the job to finish.

Contractor does the job and finishes it for the price of the contract.

Payment to contractor is usually made in sections, some to start, some half way, some at end, and then the rest after a week or two, to check the job.

Unless you ask the contractor to do extra of the contract, then the price will not change from start to finish.

Contract for 5000 to place siding on the house, then you pay 5000. Contractor short of siding half way in the job is on them, not your problem.

Can also put in contract that if they order too much, to reduce the price to what they use.  Don't want to pay for a second house.